# AddClass to random order of list items untill all have class added to them

Tags: jquery, random

Here is a way to add in sequential order, but I can figure out how to do it in random order.

Any idea on how to accomplish the random order? Here is my fiddle:

```
$("li").each(function(i,el) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $this.length);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $this.eq(random).addClass('active');
  }, i*1000); // milliseconds
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1wgwajcd/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do that

```
(function hl() {
    var li = $('li'),
        r  = Math.floor(Math.random() * li.length),
        h  = li.eq(r).hasClass('active'),
        w  = li.filter('.active').length;

    li.eq(r).addClass('active');

    if (w < li.length) setTimeout(hl, h ? 0 : 1000);
})();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/1wgwajcd/2/)

Comment: That's great, but I am running into an issue. Could you take a look at this fiddle and see if you can think of what the problem might be? http://jsfiddle.net/mBPug/35/